# Need to reload vosk model for every transcription?

Tags: python, transcription, kaldi, vosk

The vosk model that I'm using is the vosk-model-en-us-aspire-0.2 (1.4GB). Every time needs quite an amount of time to load the vosk model. Is it necessary to recreate the vosk object every time? It takes much time to load the model if we only load the model once. It can save up at least half of the time.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't required.  In many of the examples they load the model first and then perform transcription.  Your software is probably just not written correctly.

https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-server/blob/master/websocket-microphone/asr_server_microphone.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import os
import sys
import asyncio
import websockets
import logging
import sounddevice as sd
import argparse
import queue

from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer

def int_or_str(text):
    """Helper function for argument parsing."""
    try:
        return int(text)
    except ValueError:
        return text

def callback(indata, frames, time, status):
    """This is called (from a separate thread) for each audio block."""
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(audio_queue.put_nowait, bytes(indata))

async def serve_client(websocket, path):
    clients.add(websocket)
    print ("Client connected from", websocket)
    await websocket.wait_closed()
    clients.remove(websocket)

async def recognize_microphone():
    global audio_queue

    model = Model(args.model)
    audio_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    
    with sd.RawInputStream(samplerate=args.samplerate, blocksize = 2000, device=args.device, dtype='int16',
                            channels=1, callback=callback) as device:

        logging.info("Running recognition")
        rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, device.samplerate)
        while True:
            data = await audio_queue.get()
            if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
                result = rec.Result()
                logging.info(result)
                websockets.broadcast(clients, result)

async def main():

    global args
    global clients
    global loop

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--list-devices', action='store_true',
                        help='show list of audio devices and exit')
    args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()
    if args.list_devices:
        print(sd.query_devices())
        parser.exit(0)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="ASR Server",
                                     formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                     parents=[parser])
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--model', type=str, metavar='MODEL_PATH',
                        help='Path to the model', default='model')
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--interface', type=str, metavar='INTERFACE',
                        help='Bind interface', default='0.0.0.0')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, metavar='PORT',
                        help='Port', default=2700)
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--device', type=int_or_str,
                        help='input device (numeric ID or substring)')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--samplerate', type=int, help='sampling rate', default=16000)
    args = parser.parse_args(remaining)
    
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    clients = set()

    logging.info("Listening on %s:%d", args.interface, args.port)

    await asyncio.gather(
        websockets.serve(serve_client, args.interface, args.port),
                         recognize_microphone())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```